# Highlighting days in calendar widget

Tags: python, django, calendar, widget

I'm using the django admin calendar widget and would like to do highlight specific dates within the widget for display.

Is there a way to do this with the built-in django calendar widget?

Or, is there recommended widget that could be incorporated into a django project for this purpose?